# How To quickly do derivatives with respect to matrices

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, matrix, derivative

Whats a quick way to work the below (and problems similar) out?

For me to take this derivative it involves a lot of time and boring calculation, there has to be a better way.

This is taken from the solutions to Chris Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine learning:

[image: from Pattern Recogition and Machine Learning]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is something called the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), which includes a lot of identities and matrix derivatives. So if we look at eq. (88) of the Matrix Cookbook,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A} (\mathbf{x} -\mathbf{A}\mathbf{s})^T\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{x} -\mathbf{A}\mathbf{s}) = -2\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{s})\mathbf{s}^T$$

we see that this directly refers to your problem, if we assume $\Sigma^{-1}$ is a covariance matrix and therefore symmetric.

Comment: I made a couple of formatting changes - you might like to know that you can start and terminate a piece of Latex with `$$ ... $$` if you want an equation to be centre-aligned.